# Gatsby - minimal source code for DOC site

Tags: gatsby

I have forked the Gatsbyjs.org github repository and it builds without any problems locally.

I want to use the code tree as a base for technical documentation on some of my other projects. I like the layout and I have not been able to find  a solution with the same quality.

But I'm afraid that i have a lot of unnecessary code in the code tree. Can I just delete other directories than www and doc without loosing functionality?

I have not worked with Gatsby before.

Any help appreciated.

Kim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only need to keep the config files placed in the root directory (`gatsby-` prefixed files), `/src` folder (what owns all the logic, React components, etc), and `/static` (only if used). The rest of the files and folders will be automatically generated during the compilation.

Comment: Thank you, i will look into that.